# Tkinter after_idle kills toplevel

Tags: tkinter

When I setup root.after_idle() it stops the Toplevel from functioning.

```
from Tkinter import *
blah=1

def afterloop():
    label.config(text=str(blah))
    root.after(500,afterloop)

def idleloop():
    global blah
    blah=blah+1
    if blah<500000:
        root.after_idle(idleloop)

def second():
    spam=Toplevel()
    button2=Button(spam,text="Button 2",command=spam.destroy)
    button2.pack()

root=Tk()
button1=Button(root,text="Press to Open",command=second)
button1.pack()
label=Label(root,text="*********************")
label.pack()
root.update()
root.after_idle(idleloop)
root.after(500,afterloop)
root.mainloop()
```

While the after_idle is active the Toplevel is not run. Once blah is >500000 (Adjust for your machine speed) all starts working as expected. The way that I read the documentation, after_idle should only run if there is nothing else to do. In this case it appears to be blocking the processing of the Toplevel.

In real life the idletask is a fairly large state machine that is reading and writing data to and from a machining center. I know someone will suggest I use root.after(). I am, for other purposes. This code is just the least to demonstrate the problem. This works perfectly for what I want up until the Toplevel is called. You will note that idle task is still running as it eventually hits 500000 and stops.

Moving idletask to a separate thread is possible, but very much undesired at this point.

Answer (score 1):

This is an incorrect way to use `after_idle`. At the very least you need to give one millisecond between calls to it. Otherwise the event loop never gets a chance to handle any other events. What happens is that, after the first check for idle, it looks at the list of idle callbacks. If there's something there, it calls it. Then, it looks for any more to do, and continues until the callback list is empty. Only then does it return to handling normal events.

However, since you keep adding something to the list of things to do, the idle processes is effectively chasing it's own tail. It pulls one item off and does it, which pushes something on the queue. Then it pulls that item off and does it, which pushes it on the queue, and so on. You effectively have an infinite list of things it should do when it becomes idle, and it tries to do them all before relinquishing control.

Comment: Ok, I understand completely. It does leave me with two more questions. Why do the widgets on the root window continue to work? More importantly, do I understand the bit that after_idle will will only be called if there was NOTHING else to do on that pass through mainloop().